# How can I check if there are two web tabs open in Playwright?

Tags: javascript, playwright

I was wondering if there is a way to verify using playwright that there are 2 web tabs open...
In the code below I click on a button and verify that google has opened.

BUT!

I also would like to verify that there are now 2 tabs open and wanted to know if it can be done with some thing like .toHaveCount(2)

OR

would you guys recommend something better?

```js
 test('Click button link test using blank target', async () => {
    const browser = await chromium.launch();
    const context = await browser.newContext();
    const page = await context.newPage();
    await page.goto(<my weblink>);
    const newPagePromise = new Promise((resolve) => context.once('page', resolve));

    // Button locator used to click the button to open the link
    const buttonLocator = page.locator('.MuiButton-root');

    // Click the button
    await buttonLocator.click();

    // Verify that after clicking on the page that the correct URL is present
    const newPage = await newPagePromise;
    expect(newPage.url()).toContain('https://www.google.ca');
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use **[browserContext.pages()](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-browsercontext#browser-context-pages)** to get all the pages opened in the context. You can then use length and assert the values like this

```
const totPages = context.pages().length
expect(totPages).toHaveCount(2);
```

Comment: WHOA!!!
Thanks @itronic1990, that  worked beautifully !!